# Can I get force information in gazebo? and how?

Tags: ros, gazebo, force

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I want to simulate the force control of robots using gazebo. But I don't know how to get the force information in gazebo. I can get the joint position and velocity by pr2_mechanism_model::RobotState. However, there is no function to get the joint effort. Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144096/can-i-get-force-information-in-gazebo?-and-how?/) by [hannuaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/13401/hannuaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use `GetForce` in `Joint` in Gazebo's Physics library. You'll find more in [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/241/how-to-insert-a-force-or-torque-sensor-to-gazebo/) and [there](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/351/how-to-implement-a-force-sensor/).

Also, you'll get better response for Gazebo questons in http://answers.gazebosim.org.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1